# How to create view for all tables in database?

Tags: t-sql, view

I want to make views from all tables already exist  in database  that’s hard task to catch the tables one by one and make create view XXXX as select * from Table_name .I find something that it is possible with cursor and the code is :

```
DECLARE @TableName sysname
DECLARE @ColumnCount INT
DECLARE @ColumnID INT
DECLARE @SelectColumn NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = ''

DECLARE QUERYINFO CURSOR FOR
    SELECT
        t.name AS TableName,
        ccount.ColumnCount,
        c.column_id AS ColumnID,
        CASE WHEN c.column_id <> ccount.ColumnCount
                THEN c.name + ', '
             ELSE c.name
             END AS SelectColumn
    FROM sys.tables t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id=c.object_id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT object_id,COUNT(*) AS ColumnCount
        FROM sys.columns
        GROUP BY object_id
    ) ccount ON t.object_id = ccount.object_id
    ORDER BY t.Name,c.column_id

OPEN QUERYINFO
FETCH NEXT FROM QUERYINFO INTO @TableName,@ColumnCount,@ColumnID,@SelectColumn
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF @ColumnID = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = 'CREATE VIEW v_' + @TableName + ' AS SELECT ' + @SelectColumn
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + @SelectColumn
    END 

    IF @ColumnID = @ColumnCount
    BEGIN
        SET @sql = @sql + ' FROM ' + @TableName
        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql
        SET @sql = ''
    END

    FETCH NEXT FROM QUERYINFO INTO @TableName,@ColumnCount,@ColumnID,@SelectColumn
END

CLOSE QUERYINFO
DEALLOCATE QUERYINFO
```

but it has error and I don't know how solve it

Comment: Hey! Welcome to StackOverflow.  I went ahead and formatted your code so it displayed better.  To get the best eyes looking at your question, you should click on the `edit` link and at least enter a tag for which version of `SQL` you are using.  As it is right now, it might get lost in the noise as some people only look for questions with specific tags.

Comment: I never use cursors, so I rather cannot help with your code but beware of using "select *" in view definitions. If you add a column to table, the view would show something unexpected. Proper view should be defined as select columnA, columnB... not *.

Comment: @avb: a `select *` in a view definition will be expanded to the column list during view *creation*. It is not resolved each time the view is used.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: try creating such view and then "script view as alter", you will get "select *". I spent whole day trying to find out why one of views suddenly started selecting strange values. In fact it reterned values from column added to underlying table with the name of previously last column in view.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I would do with dynamic SQL; checking first to see if the view exists, then creating it with all of the columns (not by using `SELECT * FROM...`).

```
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX)
SET @SQL = N''


SELECT
    @SQL = @SQL + 
    N'IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE name = N''v_' + t.name + N''' AND type = N''V'') BEGIN DROP VIEW [v_' + t.name + '] END CREATE VIEW [v_' + t.name + N'] AS SELECT ' + 
        STUFF(
            (SELECT N',' + c.name
               FROM
                  sys.columns AS c
               WHERE 
                 c.OBJECT_ID = t.OBJECT_ID
               ORDER BY
                 column_id
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.',N'nvarchar(max)')
        ,1,1,N'')
        + N' FROM [' + t.name + N'];'
FROM
    sys.tables AS t

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: How about MySQL?

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin, I have no idea. I only have experience working in SQL Server.

Comment: Be careful if you have multiple schemas. Filter for them or include the schema name in the FROM clause

Comment: I had to add 'go' statements before and after the 'create view' (and CR/LF). SQL 2014.