# create several views in same batch in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, view, create-view

I try to run a script who create a view for each table of a specific database. 
I found this link : 
[How to create view for all tables in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23166423/how-to-create-view-for-all-tables-in-database)

and apparently, in order to work I need to add the 'GO' statement and a carriage return. So here is what I did

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQL = ''

SELECT
    @SQL = @SQL+
    N'CREATE VIEW [v2_' + t.name + N'] AS SELECT ' + 
        STUFF(
            (SELECT N',' + c.name
               FROM
                  sys.columns AS c
               WHERE 
                 c.OBJECT_ID = t.OBJECT_ID
               ORDER BY
                 column_id
               FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.',N'nvarchar(max)')
        ,1,1,N'')
        + N' FROM [' + t.name + N'] [\r\n]go[\r\n]'

FROM
    sys.tables AS t
WHERE
    t.schema_id ='1'

SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL,'[\r\n]',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
PRINT @SQL

EXECUTE (@SQL)
```

So the print result is what I expect :

```
CREATE VIEW ***** AS SELECT Parent_Path,id,a2ea,userLabel,DATE,HEURE,REF_EQT,COMMANDE_REF,LOG FROM ***** 
go
CREATE VIEW ***** AS SELECT AlarmIdentifier,Class,Category,Time,ObjectOfReference,AlarmText,DATE,HEURE,REF_EQT,SS_EQT,Carte_EQT,COMMANDE_REF,LOG FROM ***** 
go
CREATE VIEW ***** AS SELECT CELL,MCC,MNC,LAC,CID,BSC,CO,EA,RO,NCS,DATE,HEURE,REF_EQT,SS_EQT,Carte_EQT,COMMANDE_REF,LOG FROM ***** 
go
CREATE VIEW ***** AS SELECT RNC,RNCID,R1,R2,GLCNID,RNCCODEC,TB,DATE,HEURE,REF_EQT,SS_EQT,Carte_EQT,COMMANDE_REF,LOG FROM ***** 
go
CREATE VIEW ***** AS SELECT MGG,MG,RESTRICTED,DEFAULT,MISC,MGP,WF,DATE,HEURE,REF_EQT,SS_EQT,Carte_EQT,COMMANDE_REF,LOG FROM [NRGGP] 
go
CREATE VIEW ***** AS SELECT SNT,SNTV,SNTP,DIP,DEV,DEVP,SNTINL,EQLEV,PROT,SDIP,SUBSNT,DEFPST,EXTP,MG,DATE,HEURE,REF_EQT,COMMANDE_REF,LOG FROM *****
go
CREATE VIEW ***** AS SELECT RefreshLog_Id,Date,Etat,DateTransfert,Transfert FROM ***** 
go
```

but the exec line returns:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure *****, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CREATE'.
>
> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure *****, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>
> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure *****, Line 5 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   'CREATE VIEW' must be the first statement in a query batch.
>
> Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure *****, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 0]

Should I create a schema ? Any solution to my problem ?

Thank you very much

Comment: This is one place where a cursor may actually help you.  It will make it easier to iterate through all the tables and execute just one `CREATE VIEW` at a time, without needing to jump through hoops with carriage returns, etc.  Also, why not just use `SELECT * FROM blah` if you're always including every field any way?  Finally, why not just use `DECLARE @GO NVARCHAR(MAX) = CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'GO'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10);` and then append `@GO` to the end of each statement?

Comment: Also, it's possible you have a name that's too long.  Try `SELECT length, COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT LEN(name) length FROM sys.tables WHERE schema_id = 1) name_lengths GROUP BY length ORDER BY length;` to see if you have any table names already at the maximum name length?  *(128 up to 2008, and 256 from then onward.)*

Comment: @MatBailie : thank you very much for your advices, first, I don't think the problem comes from the length. Good idea about the "Go" ;) I will try with a cursor, I don't know them much but I will tcheck how to use them on Google ;)

Comment: `go` isn't a T-SQL command. It's a *client tool* command that instructs the client tools where to split a big block of text into separate batches to submit to SQL Server. Once you're running code within SQL Server, there's no client tool involved.

Comment: Thanks for the information  but I find the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a **cursor** and EXECUTE **sp_executesql** seems to work

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
       , @table_id INT
SET @SQL = ''

DECLARE CUR CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
SELECT t.object_id FROM sys.tables AS t
WHERE t.schema_id ='1'

OPEN CUR

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @table_id
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    SELECT @SQL = N'CREATE VIEW [v2_' + t.name + N'] AS SELECT ' + 
            STUFF(
                (SELECT N',' + c.name
                   FROM
                      sys.columns AS c
                   WHERE 
                     c.OBJECT_ID = t.OBJECT_ID
                   ORDER BY
                     column_id
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.',N'nvarchar(max)')
            ,1,1,N'')
            + N' FROM [' + t.name + N'];'
    FROM
        sys.tables AS t
    WHERE t.object_id = @table_id 

    PRINT @SQL
    --EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQL
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @table_id
END

CLOSE CUR

DEALLOCATE CUR
```

Comment: I've tried already with a semicolon (;) but it doesn't work either. I'll try with a cursor :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So finally I did what you guys suggested and I created a cursor, and it works. Thank you.

```
DECLARE @TableName as NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TableCursor as CURSOR

SET @TableCursor = CURSOR FOR
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo';

OPEN @TableCursor;

FETCH NEXT FROM @TableCursor INTO @TableName;

While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0

BEGIN
    EXEC ('create view '+ @TableName+'_V2 
    as select * from ' +@TableName +';')
    FETCH NEXT FROM @TableCursor INTO @TableName;
END

CLOSE @TableCursor
DEALLOCATE @TableCursor
```

Comment: be careful with select *, if you add a column in the middle of a table your views may return wrong columns

Comment: Take a look to synonyms, they may be better than use view with select *. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a syntax like this :

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [schema].[viewname] AS
SELECT * FROM schema.table

GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE VIEW [schema].[viewname] AS
SELECT * FROM schema.table

GO
```

For example :

```
SELECT 
'SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE VIEW ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' AS 
SELECT * FROM ' + TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + TABLE_NAME + ' 

GO 
'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
```

Don't forget to output results as text format (CTRL + T in SQL server Mgmt studio.) as it will keep carriage returns.

For this kind of case you can generate a script to check how SQL Server handles your script.
Just right click on your database, Tasks, Generate scripts and follow the assistant. It will output you a file exactly as SQL server waits it.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use cursors at all if you wrap every create view in a separate exec statement. then string these exec statements together with a semicolon.
Every exec call is a batch in itself, so no need to use the GO statement.
As the create statement is now a string defined within a string, you will need to escape some quotes as well. Beware though, string escaping in dynamic sql can become .... interesting as complexity rises.
like so:

```sql
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'EXEC(''CREATE VIEW ***** AS SELECT 
Parent_Path,id,a2ea,userLabel,DATE,HEURE,REF_EQT,COMMANDE_REF,LOG FROM ***** '');'+ 
'EXEC(''CREATE VIEW ***** AS SELECT AlarmIdentifier,Class,Category,Time,ObjectOfReference,AlarmText,DATE,HEURE,REF_EQT,SS_EQT,Carte_EQT,COMMANDE_REF,LOG FROM ***** '');'
print (@sql)
--sp_executeSQL @sql
```